# Is a BMX 20.75 size frame a good fit for a 5'9-6'0 rider?

Tags: bike-fit, bmx, size

I am looking into buying a BMX bike but I don't know what size frame to get to fit me.

Comment: Are you riding the bike for transportation, racing, tricks or all three? The kind of riding you will be doing determines if size matters.

Answer (score 1):

It's completely subjective and here it's unclear what the intention is of putting it in terms of a height range. Is the idea to grow into it?

Six feet is into the range where a lot of serious riders would veer bigger, given the choice. That said, if you're looking for the right compromise on a frame you're going to buy now at 5'9" and expect to grow some more inches on, yes 20.75" is a reasonable choice.